# OpenCV and Normal Bayes Classifier with custom features

Tags: c++, opencv, bayesian-networks

I'm doing a project right now for emotion recognition. What I'm doing is to detect key points in the face using an ASM model, that way I can detect points of the mouth, eyes, etc. What I want to do, is to manually define some features from these points and use them to train a Normal Bayes Classifier with OpenCV.

It's possible to do something like this with the OpenCV implementation instead using a feature extractor algorithm? Can I just create Mat objects with the features I defined? and add them to the bowTrainer? if possible, how?

I'm following this tutorial:
http://www.app-solut.com/blog/2011/07/using-the-normal-bayes-classifier-for-image-categorization-in-opencv/

thanks!!